# Grunt concat node js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

The problem is to concatenate several coffeescript files into 1.
In my *.coffee I'm using require() function. When I tried to concatenate it with grunt, it only put all my code in 1 file, but I need to remove that require() functions. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the concatenated file does not need require?

Comment: Because all my code is in 1 file. No need to require it

Comment: Isn't this what the [require.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) does?